# RegEx expression to match alphanumeric ID and sum index

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, seaborn, python-itertools

I have a directory of files in the format of `[alphanumeric]_[integer].wav` for example,

```
gdg36dhd3d_0.wav
gdg36dhd3d_1.wav
gdg36dhd3d_2.wav
344fikuo4q_0.wav
344fikuo4q_1.wav
```

The alphanumeric is the ID whereas the second number is the index. The following code should loop through a list of filenames and sum the index for each ID, and then plot a `histplot` of the data.

```
 # sum the number of isolated events for every original sample
 number_isolated_events = list()
 for k, g in itertools.groupby(isolated_filenames, key=lambda x:re.search('(\w+)_', x).group(1)):
     number_events = len(list(g))
     number_isolated_events.append(number_events)

 sns.histplot(number_isolated_events, kde=True, color='b')
```

However, the `histplot` looks like this when the above code is run and there are 20 items in `isolated_filenames`:

[image: histplot of data]

The count is 1.0, which I assume means that only one filename is being matched to the RegEx expression `'(\w+)_'`.

The x-axis is also showing what seems like the total number of indexes **combined**. I would assume a maximum of no more than 6 indexes per ID. My guess is that all the indexes have been summed and associated with the first filename rather than their respective filenames somehow. Is the issue my RegEx expression or is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: What is the expected `number_isolated_events`? Note that if you want to just sum up those `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. you can just use `sum(map(int,[x.rsplit('_')[-1].split('.')[0] for x in isolated_filenames]))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there is not an expected number per se, but on average I'd say between 3 and 6. Basically, there are multiple filenames with the same alphanumeric ID `gdg36dhd3d_0.wav`, `gdg36dhd3d_1.wav`, `gdg36dhd3d_2.wav` etc and I want to be able to sum all of the indexes for that particular ID i.e. `total for gdg36dhd3d: 3` and then plot this. I don't want to sum up every index of every ID, which is what I think your suggestion does - just the indexes of each individual ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import itertools
isolated_filenames = ['gdg36dhd3d_0.wav','gdg36dhd3d_1.wav','gdg36dhd3d_2.wav','344fikuo4q_0.wav','344fikuo4q_1.wav']
l = [(x.rsplit('_')[0], x.rsplit('_')[-1][:-4]) for x in isolated_filenames]
number_isolated_events = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    number_isolated_events.append(tuple([k, len(list(g))])) # if you need to count group items
    #number_isolated_events.append(tuple([k, sum(int(z[1]) for z in g)])) # if you need to sum numeric suffixes

print(number_isolated_events)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HDWUfx). Output:

```
[('gdg36dhd3d', 3), ('344fikuo4q', 2)]
```

Notes:

- `[(x.rsplit('_')[0], x.rsplit('_')[-1][:-4]) for x in isolated_filenames]` creates a list of file parts before `_` and the number after `_` before the `.wav` extension (I assume each file here has `.wav` extension)
- `itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0])` groups by the file "root" name (without numeric suffix)
- `len(list(g))` fetches the length of found items per key
- `sum(int(z[1]) for z in g)` sums the numeric suffixes for each file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but a question - your `isolated_filenames` contains two elements with the ID `344fikuo4q`, but the output only says 1.

Comment: @Dawn Because I *summed* the numeric suffixes. Did you mean *count* instead of *sum*? Then, you need to use `len(list(g))` instead of `sum(int(z[1]) for z in g)`

Comment: @Dawn I modified the code to return the number (=count) of the group items, not the sum of the numeric suffixes. Actually, `[:-4]` is redundant in this case, but I'll keep it since this allows more options for manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using NumPy if you are willing to use an external library:

```py
import numpy as np

isolated_filenames = [
  "gdg36dhd3d_0.wav", "gdg36dhd3d_1.wav", "gdg36dhd3d_2.wav", "344fikuo4q_0.wav", "344fikuo4q_1.wav",
]

isolated_filenames = [file_name.split("_")[0] for file_name in isolated_filenames]
number_isolated_events = list(zip(*np.unique(isolated_filenames, return_counts=True)))

print(number_isolated_events)
```

Outputs:

```
[('344fikuo4q', 2), ('gdg36dhd3d', 3)]
```